# can't past string argument to the api

Tags: angular, spring

i've created in spring the fucntion :

```
@GetMapping("/projets/traitement/{ville}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Projet>> getProjectsInTraitement(String ville) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Projets");
        List<Projet> page = projetRepository.findByVilleAndTraitement(ville);
       
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(page);
    }
```

which use the function :

```
@Query("Select p from Projet p where p.ville = :x and p.etat = 'Service'")
  List<Projet> findByVilleAndService(@Param("x") String ville);
```

i've tested the api in swagger and it's work fine.

in the angular side , i've used in the service the function :

```
 findIntraitementByCity(city: string): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    return this.http.get<IProjet[]>(`${this.cityprojectsresources}/${city}`, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

when i try to get some result by the function :
```
loadAllcityProjects(): void {
this.projetService
.findIntraitementByCity('fes')
.subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IProjet[]>) => this.filProjetcs(res.body));

```
  }
```

```
i get the issue:
com.pfe.indh.web.rest.ProjetResource     : Enter: getProjectsInTraitement() with argument[s] = [null]
and :
select projet0_.id as id1_10_, projet0_.adresse as adresse2_10_, projet0_.attribution_indh as attribut3_10_, projet0_.decision as decision4_10_, projet0_.etat as etat5_10_, projet0_.ficheinscription as ficheins6_10_, projet0_.ficheinscription_content_type as ficheins7_10_, projet0_.montant_global as montant_8_10_, projet0_.montant_solicite as montant_9_10_, projet0_.nom_societe as nom_soc10_10_, projet0_.note as note11_10_, projet0_.num_compte as num_com12_10_, projet0_.secteur as secteur13_10_, projet0_.user_id as user_id16_10_, projet0_.ville as ville14_10_, projet0_.vision as vision15_10_ from projet projet0_ where projet0_.ville=? and projet0_.etat='Traitement'
2020-06-28 09:06:23.670 DEBUG 15268 --- [ XNIO-1 task-17] com.pfe.indh.web.rest.ProjetResource     : Exit: getProjectsInTraitement() with result = <200 OK OK,[],[]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
@GetMapping("/projets/traitement/{ville}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Projet>> getProjectsInTraitement(@String ville) {
....
```

with

```
@GetMapping("/projets/traitement/{ville}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Projet>> getProjectsInTraitement
                                   (@PathVariable("ville") String ville) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @PathVaraible for accepting values when the value is passed in URL, and use
@RequestBody when the value is passed in request body, so replace your controller with

```
@GetMapping("/projets/traitement/{ville}")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Projet>> getProjectsInTraitement(@PathVariable String ville) {
            log.debug("REST request to get a page of Projets");
            List<Projet> page = projetRepository.findByVilleAndTraitement(ville);
           
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(page);
        }
```